# How can we clarify what are we actually asking, if it's locked before given any chance to respond?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators

This is my question: [Why do the Abrahamic religions tend to keep sexuality in the private sphere?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18908/why-do-the-abrahamic-religions-tend-to-keep-sexuality-in-the-private-sphere)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wHd6tuI.png]

It's locked and I have no chance to reply.

I just want to say that I agree with @fredsbend who commented there,

`Either way, the question is off-topic because it fits somewhere between general sociology and opinion based. Perhaps if the question stressed the history of the society that Abraham lived in before God came to him, then it might be on-topic.`

And just to let you know, my question ***was*** on http://history.stackexchange.com. But someone moved it here ***without*** I even had the chance to respond why I disagree with his decision to move the question here.

From the very moment I'm wondering that question, it's been a sociological question to begin with! History SE is the closest I can think of. I never try to touch the theological aspect, but a moderator on History SE disagreed anyway and moved it here. Without trying to clarify what I'm asking.

My point being:

1) Can my question get moved from here to other SE? Back to History SE I guess.

2) What's with the locking and moving every question that I've encountered here and History SE? Why don't we, as users, given the chance to clarify what we meant before the moderators take action? This question is the perfect example: moderator on History SE didn't get what I meant so he moved it here, and moderator here didn't get what I meant either, so someone locked it without trying to ask for clarification. I understand the need to maintain the StackExchange clean, but I'm not dumb. I know what I'm asking!

Comment: Locks happen automatically when migrations go wrong. The whole migration process is a little ... odd, actually. I *think* moderators can unlock. Try flagging the question and writing in a custom comment to say you want a chance to edit. Then keep an eye on [the flags page on your profile](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/3485) to see the moderators' response.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try editing [the version on History SE instead](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9800/why-do-the-abrahamic-religions-tend-to-keep-sexuality-in-the-private-sphere) if you'd prefer to try your chances there again. Again, you'd need to flag for a moderator, in that case to *undelete* your question, rather than to *unlock* it. If you take that route, you might like to pull in some examples from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-modest-should-this-site-be.

Comment: Try it now,  I tried unlocking it, but leaving it closed.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good example of why migration is problematic - often the people doing the migrating don't know the target site well enough and migrate something in that's clearly off-topic.

As to your point #2

> 2) What's with the locking and moving every question that I've encountered here and History SE? Why don't we, as users, given the chance to clarify what we meant before the moderators take action?

You've only asked 3 questions here and none of them were closed, locked, or migrated.  If you're getting a lot of that on History.SE, you'd have to ask on the meta there to find out why.